# Winappdriver and selenium in the same automated test

Tags: wpf, selenium, ui-automation, winappdriver

Hi I could do with some help / more experienced eyes.
I have a WPF application which I have started automating some UI tests for using winappdriver,   upon further investigation it has embeded html in it - webview, and can fire off requests to open the default browser with app related content - such as help files.

Has anyone had experience in working with this? For example:

- open the WPF app,
- click on help button on the WPF app which will open a browser and
- then continue the test to ensure that the correct help page has been launched with the correct content in relation to the WPF page it was fired from.

Presumably this can be done in my case with chrome driver (winappdriver cannot see the content on the webpage). I have tried using selenium's window handles, but it's like the driver can't see the already open browser page. So I am at a bit of a loss and really not sure what to do.

In previous roles I was used to using Ranorex, which does both windows and web based UI automation. So I have never had any experience using multiple driver types to do the one test.